# Undefined refernce to vtable Class(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Возникла такая ситуация: есть проект CMake, в корне папки находится главный CMakeLists, который включает директории (subdirs) и там уже находятся свои подпроекты (статические библиотеки, dll's), где и находятся исходные файлы

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(APP)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC   ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC   ON)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH   "C:\\Qt64\\5.12.1\\mingw73_64")
find_package(Qt5Widgets Qt5Core REQUIRED)
include_directories(includes gui winapi dll appapi app)

subdirs(
  winapi
  gui
  appapi
  app
        dll

)
```

Есть папка gui, которая содержит в себе определение главного окна Qt (MainWindow), это собирается без проблем
Также есть папка winapi, которая хранит заголовочный файл с классом, производным от QObject и имеющим макрос Q_OBJECT

```
class Process : public QProcess{
    Q_OBJECT
    //...
    public:
    virtual ~Process(){};
}
```

И CMakeLists это папки:

```
project(WINAPI)

set(SRC_winapi process.cpp)

set(LIBS Dbghelp Psapi)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_winapi})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Widgets)
```

Проблема в том, что подпроект GUI собирается, а WINAPI - завершается на ошибке Undefined refernce to vtable Process
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело

Comment: не разбираюсь в этом полудокументированном cmake, но похоже, что process.h не  компилится moc-ом, или moc_Process.cpp не участвует в сборке

Comment: @PavelGridin действительно, заработало... зачем мне указывать CMake этот заголовочный файл, если я подключаю его в cpp файле process.cpp?

Comment: для qmake файлы, в которых есть Q_OBJECT обязательно должны быть в списке HEADERS, чтобы откомпились moc, cpp-файлы на этот предмет никто не анализирует

Comment: @PavelGridin точно, MOC компилятор обрабатывает же только .h файлы. спасибо